# unable to import table into panda

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I'm trying to import the information from a website into a panda dataframe but it's not working. can someone shed some light on what i'm doing wrong? here's the code i have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import requests

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

url = 'https://new.cryptoxscanner.com/binance/live'
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
```

Comment: Specifically what is not working? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: `pd.read_html("http://...")` - but first check what you get with `requests.get(url)` - maybe you get empty HTML or page with warning. If page uses JavaScript to create data then you can't use `requests` or `read_html` because they don't run JavaScript. You would need `Selenium` to control web browser which runs JavaScript. You can also check if server uses some API to send data as JSON or CSV and then you don't have to scrape it from HTML.

Comment: I checked - this page uses JavaScript and WebSocket to update data on page so it will not work with requests/urllib/beautifulsoup nor read_html. it may need Selenium for this.

Comment: thanks for the feedback furas. i will look into selenium.